# duplicate class? Classes for objects

Tags: java, class, object, methods, shapes

i'm trying to make an hexagon, i have a folder name mObjects inside the folder contains Project4Tester.java and Hexagon.java. when i compile this is the error i get

2 errors found:
File: /home/user/Desktop/mObjects/Hexagon.java  [line: 4]
Error: duplicate class: mObjects.Hexagon

File: /home/user/Desktop/mObjects/Project4Tester.java  [line: 3]
Error: cannot access Hexagon
  bad source file: /home/cmehmen/Desktop/mObjects/Hexagon.java
    file does not contain class Hexagon
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.

here are both complete programs, i have not completed Hexagon due to the fact i cant get the right format for the Proect4Tester to work. can someone please tell me why i keep getting a duplicate class.... and wy project 4 cant find the Hexagon class

Hexagon.java

```
package mObjects;
import java.awt.Point;
public class Hexagon{

    private Point point;
    private int sideLength; 

    public Hexagon(Point point, int sideLength){
    }

    public Hexagon(int x, int y, int sideLength){
    }

    public void setSideLength(int sideLength){
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
    }

    public int getSideLength(int sideLength){
        return sideLength;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point point){
        this.point = point;  
    }

    public void setPoint(int x, int y){ 
    }

    public Point getPoint(){
        return point;
    }

    public double getArea(){

    }

    public double getPeremiter(){
        return sideLength*6;
    }
}
```

Project4Tester.java

```
public  class  Project4Tester  {
    public  static  void  main(String  []  args)  {
        Hexagon  p1  =  new  Hexagon(1,2,3);
        Hexagon  p2  =  new  Hexagon(new  Point(4,5),4);
        Hexagon  p3  =  new  Hexagon(new  Point(4,5),6);

        if  (p1.getPerimeter()  !=  18  ||  p2.getPerimeter()  !=  24
                                        ||  p3.getPerimeter()  !=  36)
            System.err.println("Error  1:  Perimeter  not  correct");      

        if  (  (p1.getArea()  <  23.3  ||  p1.getArea()  >  23.4)  ||
               (p2.getArea()  <  41.5  ||  p2.getArea()  >  41.6)  ||
               (p3.getArea()  <  93.5  ||  p3.getArea()  >  93.6)  )
            System.err.println("Error  2:  Area  not  correct");

        if  (  p1.getSideLength()  !=  3  ||  p2.getSideLength()  !=  4  
                                          ||  p3.getSideLength()  !=  6  )
            System.err.println("Error  3:  getSideLength  not  correct");

        p1.setSideLength(10);
        p2.setSideLength(11);
        p3.setSideLength(12);

        if  (  p1.getSideLength()  !=  10  ||  p2.getSideLength()  !=  11  
                                           ||  p3.getSideLength()  !=  12  )
            System.err.println("Error  4:  setSideLength  not  correct");

        if  (  p1.getPoint().x  !=  1  ||  p2.getPoint().x  !=  4  
                                       ||  p3.getPoint().x  !=  4    )
            System.err.println("Error  5:  getPoint  not  correct");

        p1.setPoint(3,4);
        p2.setPoint(new  Point(5,5));

        if  (  p1.getPoint().x  !=  3  ||  p2.getPoint().x  !=  5  
                                       ||  p3.getPoint().x  !=  4    )
            System.err.println("Error  6:  setPoint  not  correct");

        System.out.println("If  you  have  reached  this  point  with  no  errors  then  your  Hexagonclass  has  passed  the  pass-­‐off.");
}//end  main
}//end  class
```

i cannot change anything in Project4Tester.java